# do we have error codes for sms protocol?

Tags: java, java-me, sms, error-code

HI All
The way we have HTTP codes for acknowledgement with the server like 200 OK and error codes 404 etc , is there a way in which I can check the error code of sms for my J2ME client? I am using J2ME.. are there any API s that can be directly used to extract this information? Something on the lines of delivery report.
Regards
Garima

Comment: Do you mean when you are talking directly to some SMS enabled hardware using AT/PDU commands?

Comment: Alex: I'll bet you he's talking to some HTTP service with a very limited API.

Comment: @Christoofer ya you are right I am talking to a server with HTTP service but via SMS.. the API is limited

Comment: @Alex Ya the server understands SMS messages and responds to them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Carrier would have it's own error codes, Using a SMS Aggregator they would normally map these codes to a code that they would return to you.

Pseudo Example:

Carrier AT&T would return a error code 1001
Carrier Verizon would return a error code 20 for the same error

The Aggregator would map these different codes from the carriers to a error code: 900

Comment: thnx a lot.. can you elaborate